# How do I add naudio filters to sinewave?

Tags: signal-processing, naudio, digital-filter

I have created a sinewave using Naudio's portamento oscillator.

I would like to experiment on adding filters to it to make the sound less mechanical and I realized that Naudio has filters such as BiQuadfilters and fadeinfadeout and the examples that I came across were showing how to use these filters to an mp3 audio.

How do I add these filters to my sinewave generated from the portamento oscillator?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [equalization demo](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/tree/master/NAudioWpfDemo/EqualizationDemo) in the NAudio WPF demo source code for a basic idea of how to use `BiQuadFilter`